# Scrolling is not working when I set GestureListener to ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-gesture

I have a `ScrollView` and a nested `TextView`. When I set `setOnTouchListener` to it,the gestures are recognized but the **scrolling not working**. And If I set `setOnTouchListener` to nested `TextView`,its working fine. I have tried by googling but could not solve the problem.
But my need is to set the `setOnTouchListener`  to `ScrollView`.

Please help.

**layout.xml**

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:background="#00FF00"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        findViewById(R.id.scrollView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
                Log.e("Stark", "setOnTouchListener");
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I believe you are saying with the return true in your onTouch, that it handled the touchevent. This way ScrollView will no longer handle the touchevent (the scrolling)

Comment: You rocked. It worked by setting return to false. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to set onTouch. If only scroll up and down. Try below

```
ScrollView sv;

sv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            });
```

make sure you have this in scrollview xml. hope it helps.

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```